# Push enabled app is not listed in the Notification section in the device

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-push, android-runtime

Am converting apk to bar with push feature with reference of the below url,
http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/creating_push-enabled_android_apps.html. 
I installed the app in Blackberry Z10 and getting the device token. But my installed app is not listing the notification enabled apps section. 
Is there any other parameter to be added "android.cfg" file to make it push enabled app ?

Thanks in advance,

JRH

Answer (score 0):

If your app is push enabled then it is not automatically added to the notification section of BlackBerry settings. You have to implement notifications.

[Notifications](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_comm/notifications/index.html)